# CamelCaser function in Java, problems with debugging

Tags: java

I am creating a CamelCase function in Java that takes a string `this_is_a_sentence` and returns `ThisIsASentence` My main problem comes with handeling the different characters in the string.

So far I have:

```
  import java.util.Scanner;   

  public class Main{

     public static String camelCaser(String str){
        char[] strChr = str.toCharArray();

        strChr[0] = strChr[0].toUpperCase;

        for(int i = 0; i < strChr.length; i++){
           if (strChr[i] == '_'){
              strChr[i] = strChr[i+1].toUpperCase;
              strChr[i+1] = "";
           }
        }
        String newStr = new String(strChr);
        return newStr;
     }

     public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("String: ");
        String str = input.next();
        System.out.printf("Converting: %s into %s", str, camelCaser(str));
     }
  }
```

My main problems seems to be that you can not alter individual characters the same way that I am used to in `C`. I have read that you can use a class called `Character` but I cant figure out how to use it. The Java documentation on the matter https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html did not help me either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed around a bit of your logic to make this work. The easiest thing to make it work was to search the string for _, and then capitalize the following letter. After that, take the resulting string and remove all the _'s. It ended up like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;   

public class Caser{

    public static String camelCaser(String str){
       char[] strChr = str.toCharArray();
       strChr[0] = Character.toUpperCase(strChr[0]);
       for(int i = 0; i < strChr.length; i++) if (strChr[i] == '_') strChr[i+1] = Character.toUpperCase(strChr[i+1]);
       String reply = new String(strChr);
       reply = reply.replace("_", "");
       return reply;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("String: ");
       String str = input.next();
       System.out.printf("Converting: %s into %s", str, camelCaser(str));
    }
}
```

EDIT:

What does ***String reply = new String(strChr);*** do?

This creates a new variable named `reply`. The variable is a String. `new String(strChr)` is a helper that the String class has whereby you can give it a `char[]` and it will automatically turn it into a String.

What does ***reply = reply.replace("_", "");*** do?

`.replace(String, String)` is a String method that will search said string (in this case, `reply`) and will search for all instances of `_` and when it finds them it will replace it with an empty String (in this case, it is blank `""`).

Comment: Thank you! Would you mind explaining what this lines does:  `String reply =  new String(strChr);
       reply = reply.replace("_", "");`

Comment: 1 Note; this does not really deal with trailing ```_``` that well.

Comment: He original code did not either, hence why my code doesn't deal with it either.

Comment: @FelixRosén Updated with explanations for those two lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

This code has several problems. First, `toUpperCase()` cannot be used on a `char`, you'd need to call `Character.toUpperCase(character)`. Second, `strChar[i+1]="";` does not compile, as `""` is the empty `String`, `strChar` is a array of `char`.

I'd do something like this: first, I would split the string by "`_`" if you're sure you only want this as your separating character using `String[] words = str.split("_")`. Then, I would create a new `String` which will be the result `String` (let's call it `res`).  After that, I would loop over all elements in `words`, make the first character upper case, add it to `res` and add all the other characters of the current element to `res`.

So, it would look like this:

```
public static String camelCaser(String str){
   String[] words = str.split("_"); // split str by _
   String res = ""; // result string
   for(String word : words) {
     // first check, if words is empty
     if(!word.isEmpty()) {
        // add first character upper case
        res += Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(0));
        // add remaining characters as they are, if any
        if(word.length() > 1) {
           res += word.substring(1);
        }
     }
  }
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do something like `Character.toUpperCase(strChr[0]);` to convert a character in your array to uppercase.

Comment: so in this case `Character` = `char[] strChr` ? Dont I need to instatiate it or something?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by that. For example, your line `strChr[0] = strChr[0].toUpperCase;` would need to be changed to `strChr[0] = Character.toUpperCase(strChr[0]);`

Comment: What exactly does `Character` do? Why do we need it?

Comment: `Character` is a static class that is used to deal with single characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Character.toUpperCase(char)`.

```
public class Main{

  public static String camelCaser(String str){
    char[] strChr = str.toCharArray();

    strChr[0] = Character.toUpperCase(strChr[0]);

    for(int i = 0; i < strChr.length; i++){
      if (strChr[i] == '_'){
        strChr[i] = Character.toUpperCase(strChr[i+1]);
        strChr[i+1] = Character.valueOf('\u0000') ;
      }
     }
     String newStr = new String(strChr);
     return newStr;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("String: ");
    String str = input.next();
    System.out.printf("Converting: %s into %s", str, camelCaser(str));
  }
}
```

Comment: What does `Character` (variable, class, function) do? What is it exactly?

Comment: [The official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) says it much it better than I could. In a nutshell it's the class representation of the primitive type `char`.